# WPF Dynamic Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to iterate through all the files in a folder and dynamically create images controls for each JPEG file found. Once complete I want a form filled with dynamically created image controls (think of just about any photo viewing software such as Picasa that has a thumbnail view).

I want to be able to reorder these dynamically created images controls on the form by implementing some sort of drag drop event handler. I will not know how many images I will encounter and therefore cannot hardcode event handlers for each image control that might or might not exist. So I am looking for a way to dynamically add event handlers to dynamically created controls.

The method used in the code below is almost what I am looking for. The problem with the method below is that if I don't know the name of the control I could not hard code the event handler.

```
public partial class RoutedEventAddRemoveHandler {
  void MakeButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      Button b2 = new Button();
      b2.Content = "New Button";
      // Associate event handler to the button. You can remove the event  
      // handler using "-=" syntax rather than "+=".
      b2.Click  += new RoutedEventHandler(Onb2Click);
      root.Children.Insert(root.Children.Count, b2);
      DockPanel.SetDock(b2, Dock.Top);
      text1.Text = "Now click the second button...";
      b1.IsEnabled = false;
  }
  void Onb2Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      text1.Text = "New Button (b2) Was Clicked!!";
  } 
}
```

Note I am looking for a solution in c# code not XAML. That is a solution using code like this to add controls:

```
// What I want
Fields.Add(new Field() { Name = "Username", Length = 100, Required = true });
```

not like this:

```
// What I do not want
<TextBox Width="100" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="20" />
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? From your code it looks like you already know how to create controls in code-behind, add event handlers to them and insert them in your containers.

Comment: I know how to create controls. I have know idea what code-behind is - from what Google tells me it is related to ASP.NET and thus of no relevance here. I know how to add event handlers but I have no idea how to add event handlers for dynamically created controls. I also have no idea why this question was voted down as it seems perfectly intelligent, well researched question.

Comment: But you're doing so in your `MakeButton` method, how do you have no idea? Every time you call it you create a new button, add the `Onb2Click` handler to its `Click` event and add it to `root`.

Comment: okay. I think I might understand. You gave me too much credit the first time :-). That code came from another stackoverflow question I came across when researching the question... and I did not understand what it was doing. Awesome I had the solution and recognise it because I did not understand it. Thanks Eve. I am just going to test that and if it works I will get you to put it as an anser so I can mark it as solved for anyone else like me.

Comment: Use XAML, you'll make a mess trying to do this in code-only.  You need an ItemsControl (eg ListView) bound to a list of File objects, and a DataTemplate containing the image (Source should be bound to the file path).  You can then define whatever event handlers you want to use in the data template.

Comment: @GregSansom I am sorry but I don't understand what you are saying you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, the question says `I am looking for a solution in c# code not XAML`, so I can't post my advice as an answer.

Comment: @Eve, I have realised there is a problem in the approach above. The button b2 is hard coded all the way though the code and so I can't apply it to my images. That is I am back to the situation where I need to know the name of the control when writing the code. As I said in my question I don't know how many images there will be and so I can't assume to know the name of the control.

Comment: @GregSansom no problem. Do you have any idea how to get around the problem with Eve's approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a small sample just to save you the pain of image loading in WPF code-behind.

```
void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\img");
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(file);
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.EndInit();
        var img = new Image { Source = bitmap };
        img.MouseDown += OnImageMouseDown;
        //Add img to your container
    }
}

void OnImageMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var img = sender as Image;
    //Operate
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not do so much in codebehind. Only to get the files.
I would get an ObservableCollection where the string is the FullName of the file.
Then I would present it in a ListBox or ListView having the ItemSource bound to the collection and defining å good ItemTemplate for the control.
In the template,  you can use a Converter to create å Source for the Image in the template.